# How to position labels around circle?

Tags: c#, wpf

I’m trying to figure out how to calculate the position for text labels around a circle. This is slightly more complicated than you may think at first read .

I get the basics:

```
X = ptCenter.X + (dRadius * Math.Cos(dAngle * Math.PI / 180.0))
Y = ptCenter.Y + (dRadius * Math.Sin(dAngle * Math.PI / 180.0))
```

So, that will give me the point on the circle at angle dAngle with radius dRadius. Of course, DrawText (any variety, but I’m specifically using DrawingContext.DrawText if that makes any difference to your answer) draws with the given point as the upper left corner of the text.

Problem is, that’s not the correct position to draw the text at. Here is an illustration of the issue:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Present-your-data-in-a-radar-chart-16e20279-eed4-43c2-9bf5-29ff9b10601d

Jan is centered horizontally around the point
Feb is drawn from the lower left instead
Mar seems to be kind of in the middle horizontally
Apr is centered vertically
Etc.

The labels aren’t positioned around the point in a uniform way. It kind of depends on the angle your drawing at.

The number of labels I need to draw can vary, so hard coding fudge factors is out. Angles I need to draw at can also vary, so no fudge factors on there either. All this has to be calculated on the fly.

Kind of seems like the 0, 90, 180, 270 are special cases while the others seem to be semi centered vertically around the point, but drawn to the right or left based on which side of the circle you’re talking about?

Am I on the right track here? Or is there a “known” algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently you are going to have to calculate the center-point of the text, which of course varies on the text.. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308612/vertical-alignment-with-drawingcontext-drawtext) is an example of calculating things relative to the text itself. It looks as though the [FormattedText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) class will give you the data you need (Width, WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace, etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is center of text to be positioned on the point you calculated. So you need to shift point by half-width in X direction and half-height in Y. This will position labels "inside" the circle. Like this:

```
public class CircleText : FrameworkElement {
    public string[] Labels
    {
        get { return (string[])GetValue(LabelsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Labels", typeof(string[]), typeof(CircleText), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnLabelsChanged));

    private static void OnLabelsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        ((CircleText) d).InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
        if (Labels == null || Labels.Length == 0)
            return;
        var centerX = this.ActualWidth / 2;
        var centerY = this.ActualHeight / 2;
        var rad = Math.Min(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Length; i++) {
            var angle = 360 / (Labels.Length) * i;
            var x = centerX + rad * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
            var y = centerY + rad * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
            FormattedText text = new FormattedText(
                Labels[i],
                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Verdana"),
                12,
                Brushes.Black);
            x -= text.Width / 2;
            y -= text.Height / 2;
            drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(x, y));
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to draw lines to your points and you want labels to be outside those lines - you need to shift your labels based on cos and sin values you already calculated. This will position labels "outside", like this:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
        if (Labels == null || Labels.Length == 0)
            return;
        var centerX = this.ActualWidth / 2;
        var centerY = this.ActualHeight / 2;
        var rad = Math.Min(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Length; i++) {
            var angle = 360 / (Labels.Length) * i;
            var xshift = Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
            var yshift = Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
            var x = centerX + rad * xshift;
            var y = centerY + rad * yshift;
            drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(centerX, centerY), new Point(x,y));
            FormattedText text = new FormattedText(
                Labels[i],
                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Verdana"),
                12,
                Brushes.Black);
            x -= (1 - xshift) * text.Width / 2;
            y -= (1 - yshift) * text.Height / 2;                
            drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(x, y));
        }            
    }
```

Of course the above works for any number of labels.

Comment: thanks! I've played with your sample code for a couple of minutes (got a meeting lol), but it seems like its placing the labels in the right spots! Up voted and marked as answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are right, the problem is not so simple as it looks. After sitting down with pencil and paper I think the problem can be de-composed to simpler steps:

[image]

1. Determine dimensions of your circle and desired margin (on image: blue dashed circle).
2. Determine size of label text (on image: black frame around Label).
3. Determine point on (black) label text frame which should touch the blue dashed circle. For each dimension (X, Y) separately:

   - If the center point of text label is within half of size of label from axis (on image: within orange double line - see the label above the circle), then your point is *on the edge* of label text frame
   - Otherwise, the point is *at the corner* of label text frame.
4. 'Move' the label from the middle of the circle, so its black frame touches blue dashed line in the point you determined in step **3**. (on image: red line from center of the circle to center of the Label)
5. Based on the point which touches the circle, determine top left point of your label and draw the label at resulting position.

Sorry, no formulas here, I would need more time to compose them. But I wanted to show you that positioning labels here takes somewhat more than simple evaluation of `sin()` and `cos()` in two lines of code.

Comment: Nice response. I think that the problem is simpler, though. You have 8 possible points you need to care about: the corners and the centers of the lines of the bounding rectangle of a label. Based on the angle around the circle compute the position of the box so that the corresponding point is on the circle. For example for angle 0 you care about the left point, for angle PI/4 you care about the top left point and for PI/2 you consider the top point.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex – you have more than 8 points:  4 corners and infinity of points on each edge (not just 4) if the label is near the axis. Imagine a label exactly at the center of the axis and start moving it. Touching point won't be the corner until the label stops intersecting with axis (if the visualisation should look good).

Comment: Unless you want to actually animate the label rotating around the circle, I would be OK with the approximation, especially with a margin, as you described it. In fact, you might only need the corners, if you are OK with the label "jumping" when switching quadrants. Of course, there must be a mathematical formula somewhere, but is it really necessary?

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex – this is not about animation but about even distribution of labels. With your proposal, discrepancies won't be spotted with 5 labels around the circle, but will probably get spotted if you have 20 labels, some of them falling near the axes. I don't think that having two different calclulation cases would be difficult or time-consuming in any way. It's just about sitting down few more minutes to create appropriate formulas. :)

Comment: OK, I don't want to spend too much time with this, but consider this: in the 8 points approach, all you have to do is to use the corners for the four quadrants, except when the angle from the quadrant separator is small enough to contain half size of the text at the distance required. For example for angle close to 0 you would have -/+atan2(height/2,radius)